# how to pass password as argument to open command prompt with admin permissions in an automated way

Tags: windows, automation, command-line-arguments

Assume, i logged in with some other user.
how to pass password as argument to open command prompt with admin permissions in an automated way. Instead of manual password entry.

Tried this, but not working

```
subprocess.call(['runas', '/user:adavdom\Administrator','ca$hc0w1', 'cmd'])
```

Comment: Your scenario is unclear. What language are you using? What kind of automation are you doing? How is it triggered? Why is the user context relevant if it's automated?

Comment: It sounds a lot like you're trying to use python to automate elevation, which is not something you'd normally want to do. If it were supposed to be easy to get elevated permissions, it would be easier to do so. There are many, many security reasons why you would not want to make this an automated process.